# Large Fonts Are Not Consistent in Stack Exchange iOS App

Tags: bug, ios-app, fonts, iphone, font-size

Self explanatory on picture

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone10,4)
- OS Version: Version 13.6.1 (Build 17G80)

[image: fonts cut off vertically]